# Smooth Filled Contour

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot a filled a contour. I used `surf` for this.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar,
    view={0}{90},
    x=14 cm,
    y=7 cm,
    z=0 cm,xlabel=$z$, ylabel=$r$]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] file {Vz1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this produced a coarse filled contour:
[image]

The corresponding data file is [here.](http://pastebin.com/C2Ey62mY)

In order to get smooth filled contours, I followed [this question's second answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130802/fill-a-contour-plot)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer,patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar,
    view={0}{90},
    x=14 cm,
    y=7 cm,
    z=0 cm,xlabel=$z$, ylabel=$r$]

    \addplot3[
        contour filled={number = 30,labels={false}}, 
            thick] table {Vz1.dat};

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this throws me the following error

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/contour filled',
>   to whichyou passed 'number = 30,labels={false}', and I am going to
>   ignore it.

How do I resolve this or get a smooth filled contour?

Comment: Both examples work perfectly fine for me. Which version of PGFPlots do you have? The most recent one is PGFPlots v1.14, so maybe an update solves the problem.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I upgraded my texlive and the log file shows `(TeX Live 2016/Debian)`. But still `contour filled` throws the same error

Comment: @StefanPinnow: I just found out that my pgfplot version is 1.13. How do I upgrade it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, because the issue raised could be resolved by a package update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old pgfplot version is the culprit.(as Mr. Pinnow pointed out)

I solved it using

```
sudo tlmgr install pgfplots
```